# IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation with Authority in the same project

Tags: asp.net-core, access-token, identityserver4

One goal for our ASP.NET Core - Angular business app is to make deployments to new production servers as simple a process as humanly possible.

We want to embed an instance of IdentityServer4 in the same project as the API we wish to protect. In this setup the "Authority" URI for access token validation is the same URI as the API itself by default. How can we configure this automatically in Startup.cs without requiring that whoever is deploying the system should also manually specify the host URI in a configuration variable?

I looked into ways of programmatically retrieving the host URI inside Startup.cs (in order to configure it as the Authority for access token validation), but so far I couldn't find a reliable way to do that.

Help is greatly appreciated,
Yours,

Comment: I would suggest you to look at ASP.NET Core 2.2 which is going to be released _very soon_ (likely week for the Connect event). It has built-in support for IdentityServer for exactly the purpose of being hosted inside the API application. – Otherwise, configuring the JWT Bearer scheme is a bit more complicated since you need to dynamically resolve the current URL at the time a request comes in.

Comment: Wow, for real? Do you have a link to a relevant blog post or something?

Comment: You are right, we will definitely be using this instead
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/307, the current setup we are trying to create with IdentityServer is otherworldly complicated

Comment: Yeah, I went that route manually once before and it was pretty complicated. I might be able to extract this in a reusable way; but overall, just using the new integration will be a lot easier unless you have more complex requirements for the authentication server.